# Getting error during FB api connection

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

During connection I am getting an error. At this [site](http://iflybase.com/). When I press Log in and then agree getting error

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: FacebookApiException
>
> Message: An active access token must be used to query information
>   about the current user.
>
> Filename:
>   /data/www/iflyge/iflybase.com/application/libraries/base_facebook.php
>
> Line Number: 1340
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /data/www/iflyge/iflybase.com/application/libraries/base_facebook.php
>   Line: 911 Function: throwAPIException
>
> File:
>   /data/www/iflyge/iflybase.com/application/libraries/base_facebook.php
>   Line: 687 Function: call_user_func_array
>
> File: /data/www/iflyge/iflybase.com/application/controllers/Fb.php
>   Line: 435 Function: api
>
> File: /data/www/iflyge/iflybase.com/index.php Line: 316 Function:
>   require_once

Any Idea how can I solve this problem? Similar script works well with other web-sites

Comment: why is this in `java`?

Comment: `base_facebook.php` is part of the very old PHP SDK v3; that was not prepared for the change in access token format that occurred recently, when API v2.2 was shut down (end of March). You will either have to upgrade to a current SDK version (v5; but be aware that is completely rewritten, and will likely require major changes in your code as well), or modify the code of the v3 SDK in the relevant place(s).